# Translating an object not working as intended

Tags: python, opengl, glsl, translation, pyopengl

When I try to create a cube that can be moved around using the z-axis using a translation matrix, half of the cube doesn't render and when I try to change the z-value, the FOV seems to increase.

Is it because of the translation matrix, or is there some other error going on here, and how would I fix it?

Full code:

```
import glfw
import numpy
import pyrr
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import *
width, height = 500, 500

rot_x_var = 0
rot_y_var = 0
z = 0

def draw():
    global shader, rot_x_var, rot_y_var, z
    cube = [-0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, #red
            0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, #green
            0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, #blue
            -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, #yellow
            -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, #cyan
            0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, #pink
            0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, #half-green
            -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0] #white

    cube = numpy.array(cube, dtype = numpy.float32)

    indices = [0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 1,
               1, 2, 6, 6, 1, 5,
               5, 1, 0, 0, 4, 5,
               5, 4, 7, 7, 6, 5,
               2, 6, 7, 7, 3, 2,
               0, 4, 7, 7, 3, 0]


    indices = numpy.array(indices, dtype= numpy.uint32)

    vertex_shader_ = """
        #version 140
        in vec4 position;
        in vec3 color;
        uniform mat4 transform;
        out vec4 out_color;
        uniform ivec2 dim;
        uniform mat4 z;
        void main(){

            gl_Position = transform*vec4(position.xyz, dim.x/dim.y)*z;
            out_color = vec4(color.rgb, 0.9);

        };

    """

    fragment_shader_ = """
        #version 140
        in vec4 out_color;

        void main(){

            gl_FragColor = out_color;
        };

    """

    shader = compileProgram(compileShader(vertex_shader_, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
                            compileShader(fragment_shader_, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))
    glUseProgram(shader)
    glLinkProgram(shader)
    dim = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "dim")
    glUniform2i(dim, int(width), int(height))

    z_matrix = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "z")
    z_trans = numpy.array([0, 0, z, 0])
    glUniformMatrix4fv(z_matrix, 1, GL_FALSE, z_trans)

    VBO = glGenBuffers(1)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube.nbytes, cube, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    EBO = glGenBuffers(1)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO)
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.nbytes, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)


    position = glGetAttribLocation(shader, "position")
    glVertexAttribPointer(position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(position)
    color = glGetAttribLocation(shader, "color")
    glVertexAttribPointer(color, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, ctypes.c_void_p(12))
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(color)


    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    rot_x = pyrr.Matrix44.from_x_rotation(rot_x_var)
    rot_y = pyrr.Matrix44.from_y_rotation(rot_y_var)
    transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "transform")
    glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, rot_x * rot_y)






def Screen():
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL)
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 64, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)
    draw()
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)


def main():
    global width, height, rot_x_var, rot_y_var, z
    if not glfw.init():
        return
    window = glfw.create_window(500, 500, "PyOpenGL GLFW", None, None)
    if not window:
        glfw.terminate()
        return

    glfw.make_context_current(window)

    while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
        glfw.poll_events()
        if glfw.get_key(window, glfw.KEY_DOWN) == glfw.PRESS:
            rot_x_var += 0.01
        if glfw.get_key(window, glfw.KEY_UP) == glfw.PRESS:
            rot_x_var -= 0.01
        if glfw.get_key(window, glfw.KEY_RIGHT) == glfw.PRESS:
            rot_y_var += 0.01
        if glfw.get_key(window, glfw.KEY_LEFT) == glfw.PRESS:
            rot_y_var -= 0.01
        if glfw.get_key(window, glfw.KEY_E) == glfw.PRESS:
            z += 0.1
        if glfw.get_key(window, glfw.KEY_Q) == glfw.PRESS:
            z -= 0.1
        Screen()
        width, height = glfw.get_window_size(window)



        glfw.swap_buffers(window)

    glfw.terminate()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Update:** I have tweaked around with the code, and now the cube is not being shown, instead of the cube being deformed. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found the error. It was with this line:

```
z_trans = numpy.array([0, 0, z, 0])
```

I had to convert it to a matrix instead of an array.

```
z_trans = pyrr.Matrix44([1, 0, 0, 0,
                         0, 1, 0, 0,
                         0, 0, 1, z,
                         0, 0, 0, 1])
```